# Reactjs based web pages are not working with phantomjs headless

Tags: python, reactjs, phantomjs

I am working UI-Testing for  mailapp.I wrote all test cases  and they are working fine on chrome and firefox.
When I am trying to run in Phantomjs for headless testing ,phantomjs is able to locate all elements on html web pages such as  it is working fine with logging but is not able to locate any elements in reactJS based web pages.phantomjs version is 2.1.1
I have searched all stackoverflow posts but nothing worked.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance.

```
 search_field=driver.find_element_by_id('search_text')
 search_field.send_keys(field_name)
```

It is giving output as

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with id 'search_text'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"92","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:55059","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"id\", \"sessionId\": \"75163a30-4cfc-11e7-8ad5-2f1b822b374a\", \"value\": \"search_text\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/75163a30-4cfc-11e7-8ad5-2f1b822b374a/element"}}
```

Comment: at the moment when test script runs react components are probably not yet loaded. you have to wait

Comment: I tried time.sleep and wait also.

Comment: even with waits also it is displaying same output .

Comment: try to save html to a file using phantomjs api and check manually if element is present

Comment: I am new to Phantomjs.can you please share python code or reference docs

Comment: here's write example and many others  http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/write.html

Comment: Since my website has dynamically changing to so many web pages  , it is very difficult to save every page every time. Can you suggest me why my python code is not working which is even working in Firefox and chrome.